How to navigate between two pages in XAML and win32more
I want to create a window desktop UI and I am  stuck on navigation between tow pages in XAML and win32more so help me to fix this problem. Firstly I create a page using XAML and run this application using win32more.In win32more code I find the button but this code send back a error is button not found so tell me how can i fix this issue.
this is the win32more code.
from win32more.xaml import XamlApplication
from win32more.Microsoft.UI.Xaml import Window
from win32more.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls import Page, Button, Frame
from win32more.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup import XamlReader

class MainPage(Page):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        super().__init__()
        self.frame = frame 
        try:
            
            with open("page1.xaml", "r") as file:
                self.Content = XamlReader.Load(file.read())
                if self.content:
                    print("xaml content loaded succesfuly...")
                else:
                    print("xaml content not loaded..")

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"cann't load file...{e}")
 
        get_started_button = self.FindName("GetStartedButton")
        if get_started_button:
            print("Button found!")
            get_started_button.Click += self.GetStartedButton_Click
            print(get_started_button)
        else:
            print("button not found")
    
    def GetStartedButton_Click(self, sender, e):
        
           
        second_page = SecondPage()
        self.frame.Navigate(second_page)

  
class SecondPage(Page):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        with open("page2.xaml", "r") as file:
            self.Content = XamlReader.Load(file.read())

class App(XamlApplication):
    def OnLaunched(self, args):
        win = Window()
        win.Title = ""        
        win.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = True
        win.SetTitleBar(None) 
        frame = Frame()

        main_page = MainPage(frame)
        frame.Content = main_page
        win.Content = frame

        win.Activate()

XamlApplication.Start(App)


this is XAML code.
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     >
    <Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image Source="https://gurpreetsingh.aliens.school/whatsapp.png" 
               Width="450" Height="550" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,155,0,0"/>
        
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,455,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="Welcome to WhatsApp" FontSize="24" Padding="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock Text="A simple, reliable, and private way to use WhatsApp on your computer." FontSize="13" Padding="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,2,0,0" />
            <Button Name="GetStartedButton" Content="Get Started" Click="GetStartedButton_Click" />
            <TextBlock Text="Version 2.2247.3.0" FontSize="14" Padding="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,15,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>        
    </Grid>
</Page>


